# CSUM's md5 calculation is different from fciv

Tags: md5, fciv

Is any reason why calculated by CSUM MD5 hash is different from the same hash calculated by fciv program on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If FCIV output is set to XML,  the hexadecimal hash values are stored in base64 encoded format. When you view the XML database directly, the base64 encoded representation of the hash value does not visually match the hexadecimal value that the console displays. FCIV decodes the base64 encoded hashes when it displays the contents of the database to the screen. Therefore, it displays the correct hexadecimal value.

try: fciv.exe -list -md5 -xml hashdb.xml